# Low Quality Posts reviews add comments more than once on behalf of reviewer

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17651376/1369235) came in *Low Quality Posts* review which was [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2509949) as "This is commentary on another post, not an answer" by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458648/deepu)*. But the comment was added **5 times** automatically on behalf of that user.

> [image]

First four comments' time is `2013-07-15 10:23:18Z` while the last one's time is `2013-07-15 10:23:19Z`. Those comments are still exist. 10K+ users can see that.

Is this a bug or something else?

<sup>* Because the comment is added on behalf of that user.</sup>

Comment: +1 for a nice study hand there

Comment: Maybe the user quickly clicked five times on the flag submit button, hence sending five similar flags?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Clicking once will close the popup. :)

Comment: And even if you could click to reopen the popup and resend the same flag 5 times in one second, isn't it rate-limited?

Comment: Flag will be auto converted to close vote right? Meaning I can retract it?

Comment: OK, you're right. I was able to click more than once but red message appeared saying I can't flag/vote again on same post. @Wooble

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah. Also the post I am talking about is an answer.

Comment: No doubt it shouldn't have happened but can't see it anywhere else. Maybe temporary glitch..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not sure but after a looong search I found [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2515530)

Comment: Weird indeed. Let's hope a dev will come by and explain... where's Oded when we need him? ;)

Comment: Saw this on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532600/610573