# Is the LQP queue adding multiple comments?

Tags: bug, comments, review, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

I've just seen a number of posts in the Low Quality Posts queue which appear to have multiple identical automatic comments from a reviewer:

- [Example 1: 2 identical comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145483/how-to-assign-values-to-a-char-array/21145513#21145513) (now deleted; 10K+ only)
- [Example 2: 4 identical comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303066/what-could-be-causing-an-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found/23110811#23110811) (now deleted; 10K+ only)
- [Example 3: 3 identical comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79197/combining-two-syndicationfeeds/23113805#23113805) (now deleted; 10K+ only)

Given that all the comments have almost identical timestamps, this seems to be a bug.

<sup>Obviously, I can just flag these for deletion, but I haven't yet because I want to make sure non-moderators can see this behavior.</sup>

Comment: hiccup, maybe?? But I've seen this before [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212174/how-were-multiple-comments-posted-inside-rate-limit) with multiples inside the rate limit.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, that appears to be the same issue. It seems that this issue is specific to the LQP queue.

Comment: @gnat It's not a duplicate of that question. I'm aware of what process is adding those comments. I'm pointing out that there seems to be a bug in the process.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's seems like a dup of the one I asked about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212174/how-were-multiple-comments-posted-inside-rate-limit

Comment: @bluefeet Agreed, looks like this has been noticed by others as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer?rq=1 (note: I did search before posting this question, but didn't find any info on this)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not