# A spasm of duplicate comments

Tags: bug, automatic-comments

It's not hugely important because this answer will be gone soon enough...

I just [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4742057) on the SO low quality review queue. Either something has a spasm (and is buggy) or this user really really really meant what he said:

[image]

Comment: @hims056 Good find, didn't realise it was a dupe. I've voted to close (although it's interesting to note the problem still exists).

Comment: Actually it's not a good find. It's my own question. :-)

Comment: @hims056 Ahh so it is - I didn't read that far. Have a +1. Interesting to see that this incident is also 5 comments, bit of a co-incidence.

Comment: There is also [an incidence](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2515530) of two comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Low Quality Posts reviews add comments more than once on behalf of reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Low Quality Posts reviews add comments more than once on behalf of reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Low Quality Posts reviews add comments more than once on behalf of reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer)