# Error message in LQP queue asking me to "Please try again" led to multiple comments posted

Tags: bug, comments, review, low-quality-posts

I checked the LQP queue and there was an answer with a score of 1. As it had a positive score, I was given the option to Recommend Deletion. I first downvoted the post to 0 from the review page, then attempted to complete the review with Recommend Deletion. It did not work, and I received a red error message, which I unfortunately do not have a screen shot of, suggesting that I "Please try again." So I tried again, and got the same message.

I then refreshed the page, and Recommend Deletion had been changed to Delete, and I was able to complete the review. However, when I returned to the answer on the Q&A page, I was met with this in the comment section:

[image]

Despite not being able to complete the review, it appears as though my attempts still generated the reason I had chosen in the comments on the answer.

This appears to be a different bug than the one described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer), as that question is multiple comments posted at the same time from a single successful attempt at the review. The timestamps in my screenshot correspond to the time it took me to retry the review.

This happened on RPG, [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/76852) is the review page for the particular review.

Comment: Clearly the system just _really_ wanted to get your message across to the OP.

Comment: It seems that in the previous review UI, [you weren't able to vote from within the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228738/377214), so the code wasn't designed to take this into account. However, it seems like this was (not sure if intentionally or accidentally) enabled with the new review UI improvements, resulting in the issue here.

Comment: At a guess, your action was received by the SE server, but its response back to your browser didn't make it to you. Which looks just like what you get if the notification for your action is not received by the server. From the browser's perspective your action was unsuccessful and it shows the error (something I've occasionally seen). The fix would need to server to check if the action has been done already but still return the "action completed" reply.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The time stamp on the review completion corresponds to the timestamp of the last comment. If your description were the case, wouldn't the review timestamp match the timestamp of one of the earlier comments?